# Can I get the rect.x from one class to use in another class?

Tags: python, class, pygame

So basically I want to my Road class to always know where my Car (Player1) class is so road knows whether to slow down as Car has left road (or be able to speed back up when Car gets back within road area.

As Car only moves left / right and it is the road that speeds up coming down screen, I figured a way to mimic the car using a "self.where_player" at same start position and then add / subtract x position and follow it with key's pressed (a, d), but after awhile it can lose Car placement as Car can either have x values added or subtracted while slipping left or right on ice or have it keys (a, d) temporarily disabled if spinning on oil, while the road does not know these things...

If I could figure out how the Road class could "always" know where the Car class rect.x was, well that would be fantastic!

```
import pygame

W = 1000
H = 800
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))

class Road1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, top, player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        bkgrnd = pygame.image.load("Images/Road.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(bkgrnd, (300, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (120, top))
        self.top = top
        self.speedy = 0
        self.player = player
        self.out_of_bounds = False

    def update(self):
        self.top += self.speedy
        if self.top >= 800:
            self.top = self.top - 900
        self.rect.top = self.top
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.speedy = min(20, self.speedy + 0.25)
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.speedy = max(0, self.speedy - 0.25)

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.player -= 5
        if self.player <= 120:
            self.player = 120
            self.out_of_bounds = True
            if self.out_of_bounds and self.speedy > 5:
                self.speedy -= 0.35
            else:
                self.out_of_bounds = False

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.player += 5
        if self.player >= 420:
            self.player = 420
            self.out_of_bounds = True
            if self.out_of_bounds and self.speedy > 5:
                self.speedy -= 0.35
            else:
                self.out_of_bounds = False
```

The following is a portion from the Main page enough to make Road work:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
# from Ice_Patch import Ice1, Ice2
# from Oil_Slick import Oil1, Oil2
from Player1 import Player1, car1_image
# from Player2 import Player2, car2_image
from Roads import Road1, # Road2

W, H = 1000, 800
HW, HH = W / 2, H / 2
AREA = W * H
FPS = 30
GREEN = (0, 200, 0)
pygame.init()
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Fury")


def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

player = Player1()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
road = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(9):
    rd = Road1((i - 1) * 100, player)
    all_sprites.add(rd)
    road.add(rd)

while True:
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    events()
    all_sprites.update()
    DS.fill(GREEN)
    all_sprites.draw(DS)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Player1 Class:

```
import pygame
W = 1000
H = 800
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
car1_image = pygame.image.load("Images/GalardB.png").convert_alpha()
car1_image = pygame.transform.scale(car1_image, (40, 70))
GREY = (211, 211, 211)
ANIM_DELAY = 50
POWERUP_TIME = 5000
SPIN_TIME = 1950

class Player1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, car1_image, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = car1_image
        self.image.set_colorkey(GREY)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.radius = 25
        self.speedx = 0
        self.rotations = [self.image]
        self.spinning_since = 0
        self.rotate()
        self.damage = 100
        self.shoot_delay = 250
        self.last_shot = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.lives = 3
        self.hidden = False
        self.hide_timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.score = 0
        self.crashx = 0
        self.crashy = 0
        self.power = 0
        self.power_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.not_spinning = True

    def update(self):
        if self.power >= 1 and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.power_time > POWERUP_TIME:
            self.power -= 1
            self.power_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if self.hidden and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.hide_timer > 1500:
            self.hidden = False
            self.rect.center = (300, 700)
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate1[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.shoot()
        if self.not_spinning:
            if keystate1[pygame.K_a]:
                self.speedx = -5
            if keystate1[pygame.K_d]:
                self.speedx = 5
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > 420:
            self.rect.right = 420
        if self.rect.left < 120:
            self.rect.left = 120
        if self.spinning_since > 0:
            time_spinning = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.spinning_since
            if time_spinning >= SPIN_TIME:
                self.spinning_since = 0
                index = 0
                self.not_spinning = True
            else:
                index = int(time_spinning / ANIM_DELAY)
                index %= len(self.rotations)
                self.not_spinning = False
            cx, cy = self.rect.center
            self.image = self.rotations[index]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = cx
            self.rect.centery = cy

    def powerup(self):
        self.power += 1
        self.power_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def shoot(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_shot > self.shoot_delay:
            self.last_shot = now
            if self.power == 0:
                pass
            if self.power >= 1:
                bullet1 = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
                all_sprites.add(bullet1)
                bullets1.add(bullet1)

    def rotate(self):
        ROT_FRAMES = 36
        for i in range(ROT_FRAMES):
            angle = i * (720 / ROT_FRAMES)
            rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, angle, 1)
            self.rotations.append(rotated_image)

    def spin(self):
        if self.spinning_since == 0:
            self.spinning_since = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        else:
            pass

    def slide(self):
        keystate1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate1[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.x -= 2
            self.rect.x -= 1.5
            self.rect.x -= 1
            self.rect.x -= 0.5
            self.rect.x -= 0.25
        if keystate1[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.x += 2
            self.rect.x += 1.5
            self.rect.x += 1
            self.rect.x += 0.5
            self.rect.x += 0.25

    def hide(self):
        self.crashx = self.rect.x
        self.crashy = self.rect.y
        self.hidden = True
        self.hide_timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.rect.center = (W * 2, H * 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to make the "road" knowing the player. Add an attribute `player` the class `Road1`:

```py
class Road1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, top, player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.player = player

        # [...]
```

Instead of `self.where_player` you can directly ask `self.player` for its position.

Pass the player to the road objects when they are constructed. e.g.:

```py
player = Player1(?????)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
road = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(9):
    rd = Road1((i - 1) * 100, player)
    all_sprites.add(rd)
    road.add(rd)
```

---

An other option would be to add an argument `player` to the method `update`:

```py
class Road1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self, player):
        # [...]
```

Of course you have to separate the update of road and player. e.g.:

```py
player.update()
road.update(player)
```

Comment: Rabbid76, I've tried your suggestions but with no luck - maybe it is how I have my Player1 set up? I've edited my question to include the Player1 class and the changes I made per your suggestion... and I am getting an "__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: car, x, y" error - I have tried putting in these arguments but then get a completely different error.

Comment: If I add the car1_image and 270, 700 for the three aruments I get error:     File "C:\Users\House\PycharmProjects\Scrolling\Roads.py", line 31, in update
    if self.player <= 120:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Player1' and 'int'

Comment: @Cieszkowski `player = Player1()` is just an example. You have to place your code instead. I had no idea about your player class (I could not see it). How did you create the player instance before? Of course it has to be something like `player = Player1(car1_image, 123, 456)`

Comment: Rabbid67, I've tried all sorts of ways based on your suggestions above but still cannot make it work. When I ask 'if self.player <= 120" in the update of class Road I get a type error '<=' not supported between instances of 'Player1' and 'Int'...... Player1 has car1_image, x, y - how do I ask self.player of Player1's x spot?

Comment: @Cieszkowski `self.player` is an instance of `Player1`. Of course you have to use `self.player.rect.x`, `self.player.rect.y` or `self.player.rect.centerx`, `self.player.rect.centery`.

Comment: Rabbid76... Awesome!!!! Apparently I was having brain fart and didn't see the obvious. Thanks again for the help and insight. I look everywhere on the internet about using one classes attribute in another classes and it was either "can't be done" or suggestions so very convoluted. The above was very simple and seamless - I've learnt something new again for future projects.